# Online database connection not working

Tags: java, mysql

I was created online mysql database in jelastic.com. and I try to connect the database using my java code but it's not working and no error will be displayed
the following code is I used.

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql36157-databasePro.whelastic.net/Raptor","XXXXX","XXXXX");
  Statement st=connection.createStatement();
```

i don't know why it's not working can any one help me to fix this

Comment: @Incognito No error was displayed it enter into my servlet and just idle

Comment: There should be somewhere or the server is just so slow. Check the log files if ever there's any.

Comment: try to use a ssh portforwarding ssh -L3306:127.0.0.1:3306 NAME@HOST and change the HOST in you java code to localhost - if it works you mysql database cannot talk to the outside.

Comment: So, here Raptor is your db Name. Try adding port no. as 3306 after mysql36157-databasePro.whelastic.net (mysql36157-databasePro.whelastic.net:3306)

Comment: Try to connect manually over ssh with the same credentials?

Comment: @Ouney i tried what you but still not working

Comment: in case you are not sure what is happening. Try printing schemaName from connection. Sop(connection.getSchema()) and see what does it do.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try to ping `mysql36157-databasePro.whelastic.net` in your command line and see if it works. Then you should try adding port `3306` to your url and make sure it's the correct port.

Comment: ping was success fully working but after adding 3306 port in my java code still no improvement

Comment: How about telnet `mysql36157-databasePro.whelastic.net 3306`? Are you sure that the port is correct?

Comment: when I use telnet command it shows  telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

Comment: So, that's the problem. You cannot connect to this port. You need to make sure if there's something wrong with this port or it's not this port being used here.